# Develop an IOS Application with Push Notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am planning to develop an IOS Application with Push Notification.

Is there any links/tutorials or anything that was proven helpful you would recommend?

I am more curious about the Push Notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this two parts tutorial from Ray Wenderlich:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

and

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 0):

Hosting your own APNS client is not for the faint of heart. A service like http://urbanairship.com/products/push-messaging is a better way to get started with APNS.